# enabling Elasticsearch in JHipster results in UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name ‘userService’

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, jhipster

I've been trying to build an app with JHipster that can use some advanced filtering, in particular ElasticSearch. Why does it fail when I run it out of the box, without even editing the project ?

I am running the following software in Windows 10:

- Java v15.0.2
- node v14.17.4
- NPM 6.14.14

Same happens in Ubuntu with:

- Java v17.0.1
- node v16.14.0
- NPM 8.5.0

The problem I have is very easy to reproduce:

1. Go to the online version https://start.jhipster.tech/generate-application
2. Leave everything as it is, and mark the option "Search engine using Elasticsearch"
3. Click on Download as ZIP file
4. Unpack and run with ./mvnw

---> the build is compiled but it fails to launch because it can't instantiate the bean ‘userService’

**Full trace:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\projects\JHipster\sample\target\classes\com\mycompany\myapp\service\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepository' defined in com.mycompany.myapp.repository.search.UserSearchRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on DatabaseConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]]; nested: ExecutionException[java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]]; nested: ConnectException[Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]];
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
        at com.mycompany.myapp.JhipsterSampleApplicationApp.main(JhipsterSampleApplicationApp.java:69)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepository' defined in com.mycompany.myapp.repository.search.UserSearchRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on DatabaseConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]]; nested: ExecutionException[java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]]; nested: ConnectException[Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]];
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]]; nested: ExecutionException[java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]]; nested: ConnectException[Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]];
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$instantiateClass$5(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:258)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.instantiateClass(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:543)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:74)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:322)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:328)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]]; nested: ExecutionException[java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]]; nested: ConnectException[Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]];
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:72)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.translateException(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:427)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:410)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.doExists(RestIndexTemplate.java:103)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractIndexTemplate.exists(AbstractIndexTemplate.java:134)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:92)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)
        ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2078)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1732)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1717)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.exists(IndicesClient.java:963)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.lambda$doExists$2(RestIndexTemplate.java:103)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:408)
        ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.getValue(BaseFuture.java:262)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.get(BaseFuture.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture.get(BaseFuture.java:76)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2075)
        ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]
        at org.apache.http.nio.pool.RouteSpecificPool.timeout(RouteSpecificPool.java:169)
        at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.requestTimeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:632)
        at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool$InternalSessionRequestCallback.timeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:898)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionRequestImpl.timeout(SessionRequestImpl.java:198)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processTimeouts(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:213)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:158)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Exception in thread "Logback shutdown hook [default]" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1013)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:967)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.fireOnReset(LoggerContext.java:323)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.reset(LoggerContext.java:226)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.stop(LoggerContext.java:348)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.hook.ShutdownHookBase.stop(ShutdownHookBase.java:39)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook.run(DelayingShutdownHook.java:57)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]]; nested: ExecutionException[java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]];

If you look further in your stacktrace you can see that the application simply cannot connect to localhost:9200 which is the default address of an Elasticsearch local instance.

You firstly need to run elasticsearch on your machine in order for the application to work. You can do it quickly in docker
https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/

Install docker, then type to download the image:

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.0.0
```

After you can launch the container with elasticsearch

```
docker run --name es01 -p 9200:9200 -it docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.0.0
```

Comment: Than you! In development, JHipster runs with an embedded Elasticsearch instance (source: https://www.jhipster.tech/using-elasticsearch/ ).  I will try running an external one as you suggest, and see how it goes.

Comment: I hope it helps, didn't know about the embedded instance!

Comment: I have it working now, thank you! It seems that the embedded version stopped working years ago: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7862

Comment: Glad I could help!